# Bind a single key in xmonad without using a ModMask

Tags: xmonad

I would like to bind single key presses to certain actions in my xmonad.hs.

I'm setting up a security system and will have each workspace on xmonad running a camera view.  I want to bind single keys, such as left or right, to the switching of the workspaces instead of requiring to also press a modmask along with the key.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer,

Put a zero in place of the modkey:
Instead of this:
((modm              ,xK_a), prevWS)
This:
((0              ,xK_a), prevWS)

Comment: Possibly `noModMask :: KeyMask` from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11-1.9.1/docs/Graphics-X11-Types.html might also be suitable.